# Template specialization priorities when using pointers or references

Tags: c++, inheritance, template-specialization

I have a Serializer class like this:

```
class Serializer
{
public:
    // Func 1 (default)
    template <class T>
    void Serialize(T* pValue)
    {
        SerializeInternal(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pValue), sizeof(*pValue));
    }

    // Func 2 (specialization)
    template <> 
    void Serialize<Serializable>(Serializable* pSerializable)
    {
        pSerializable->Serialize(*this);
    }

protected:

    // Implemented by input and output serializers
    virtual void SerializeInternal(char* pData, size_t size) = 0;
};
```

Now my problem is when I have classes that inherit the Serializable interface they will always be handled by Func 1, even though I want them to be handled by Func 2 (pointers or references doesn't matter they both behave equally). It seems like C++ doesn't recognize that the Serializable interface is inherited unless you clearly specify that:

```
SerializableClass sc; // Inherits Serializable
InputSerializer s; // Inherits Serializer

s.Serialize(&sc); // Func 1 is called >:(
s.Serialize<Serializable>(&sc); // Func 2 is called
```

Now as soon as I forget to add `<Serializable>` somewhere the program of course bugs out, which is pretty annoying.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: This seems to be a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371699/mixing-template-function-overloading-and-inheritance

Comment: Checked it out and yes it's indeed the same thing. And there the Boost functionality was again the solution. I guess I have to accept there is no pure C++-solution to this (there was a good explanation to why it won't work in that thread as well).

Comment: The boost solution should contain nothing that is not pure C++. In C++0x, `type_traits` and `enable_if` are parts of the standard library. The latter is trivial to write yourself, `is_base_of` might be trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like C++ doesn't recognize that the Serializable interface is inherited unless you clearly specify that

This is true. If you have some class

```
class SerializableClass : public Serializable
```

only `SerializableClass`, not `Serializable`, is considered when deducing the `T` parameter.

If what you need is create two functions, one taking any pointer, the other taking a pointer to anything derived from Serializable, you can create two overloads and use SFINAE to select the narrower one when possible.

```
template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if_c<!boost::is_base_of<Serializable, T>::value, void>::type foo(T*) { ... }

template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_base_of<Serializable, T>, void>::type foo(T*) { ... }
```

If you don't want to use boost, you can implement required functionality akin to [this](http://ideone.com/AnPHR).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using Boost and I'm not going to start using it just for this. So a non-Boost solution (if at all possible) would be nice.

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha: It's fairly trivial to write your own type traits. Most modern Standard libraries include them anyway - they're part of TR1.

Comment: The question then is; if Boost use functionality that is already available in C++, then what does it use in is_base_of? The only two reasonable options I've found is a comparison using typeid() which is compiler dependent or using dynamic_cast which is slow as hell. Neither very good solutions.

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha: See the link I added to the end. Not sure if boost actually uses this (it's a fairly crude way of doing that), but it's one possibility to implement it.

Comment: Thanks just found a similar (same?) implementation which I posted as my own answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910979/how-is-base-of-works

Answer (score 0):

Use an overload instead of a template specialization!

Answer (score 0):

I found a link explaining how `boost::is_base_of` works: [How does `is_base_of` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910979/how-is-base-of-works)

Apparently they use some pretty fancy template-fu magic to get it to work. I can "easily" write a similar function myself.

When you're not clever enough to solve it yourself, look at the pros ;)