# C++ function overload

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overloading

I know that in C++ functions can be overloaded by their const property, but I got an error when I run this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

template<class T> class Array
{
public:
    Array() : data(0), sz(0){}
    Array(unsigned size) : sz(size), data(new T[size]){}
    ~Array() 
    {
        delete[] data;
    }

    const T& operator[](unsigned n) const
    {
        if(n >= sz || data == 0)
        {
            throw "Array subscript out of range";
        }
        return data[n];
    }

    T& operator[](unsigned n)
    {
        if(n >= sz || data == 0)
        {
            throw "Array subscript out of range";
        }
        return data[n];
    }

    operator const T*() const
    {
        return data;
    }

    operator T*()
    {
        return data;
    }

private:
    T* data;
    unsigned sz;
    Array(const Array& a);
    Array& operator=(const Array&);
};

int main()
{
    Array<int> IntArray(20);

    for(int i = 0; i != 20; ++i)
    {
        IntArray[i] = i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error comes from `IntArray[i] = i;` the complier says that it can't find the proper overload function.
shouldn't it call `T& operator[](unsigned n)` ??

I'm using vs2010 as my complier

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519282/why-is-this-ambiguity-here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call is ambiguous because the code requires a conversion (the index is `int` and your `operator[]` expects a value of type `unsigned`) and as the error message says, there a multiple possible conversions.  (This would not be the case if you did not provide the `operator T*` conversion operator.)

> error C2666: 'Array::operator []' : 4 overloads have similar conversions
>   could be
>
> - 'int &Array::operator [](unsigned int)'
> - 'const int &Array::operator [](unsigned int) const'
> - 'built-in C++ operator[(const int *, int)'
> - 'built-in C++ operator[(int *, int)'
>
> while trying to match the argument list '(Array, int)' with  [T=int]

Just change your for loop to use an index of type `unsigned` so that it can select the proper overload.

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i != 20; ++i)
{
    IntArray[i] = i;
}
```

By the way, offering direct conversion to pointer types is usually considered a Bad Idea (TM) because it enables this syntax:

```
Array<int> array(20);
delete array;
```

Comment: Alternatively, add overloads for `T& operator[](int n)` and the `const` variant so an `int` index doesn't need a conversion.  It's a bit more code, but might make for a less frustrating experience using the class.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Indeed, but it would probably be a better choice to simple remove the "conversion to pointer" operators.  `std::vector<>` doesn't provide an `operator[](int)` and does not produce this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should call `T& operator[](int n)`.

This works:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i != 20; ++i)
{
    IntArray[i] = i;
}
```