# Overloaded function. Why it's ambiguous here?

Tags: c++

I have my function overloaded in code below:

```
void function(char x, double y) {
    cout << "char, double" << endl;
}

void function(int x, int y) {
    cout << "int, int" << endl;
}

int main() {
    function('a', 'b');
    return 0;
}
```

When i try to compile it says me: "[Warning] ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second"

How does compiler make implicit conversions here so that it's ambiguous which candidate is right?

Comment: You also forgot the return type (which defaults to `int` IIRC).

Comment: @Jefffrey Not in C++, there it's simply an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this ambiguity here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519282/why-is-this-ambiguity-here)

Answer (score 10):

The literal constants `'a'` and `'b'` have type `char`, so there is no exact match.  The ambiguity occurs because the first parameter matched the first function, but the preferred conversion of the second is to `int`, matching the second function.

GCC is very explicit about this, issuing the following diagnostic:

> warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second

GCC seems to be saying, I could resolve this for you, but ISO C++ won't allow it.  Type agreement is however important to good code quality and avoidance of errors.

You can coerce the selection by casting:

```
function( static_cast<int>('a'), static_cast<int>('b') );
```

or by supplying a `function( char, char )` overload.

Comment: @Jefffrey `C++11[conv.fpint]`. Note that `char` is an integer type.

Comment: @Jefffrey: what Angew said.  A `char` is an integer type, promotion and conversion rules apply. To answer your question, no I cannot tell you where in the standard it says that, the standard is fine for compiler writers and settling arguments of forums, but I tend to go with 25 years experience ;-)

Comment: @Jeffrey `[conv]`: "Standard conversions are **implicit conversions** with built-in meaning ... A standard conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order: ... Zero or one conversion from the following set ... floating-integral conversions." (emph. mine)

Comment: This doesn't explain why the overload resolution fails, however.  The fact that `char` to `int` is a promotion, and not a conversion, is critical to the understanding here.

Comment: @JamesKanze:  A char can be promoted to int and converted to double.  Both assignments `double a = 'a'` and `double b = 10` are valid (by promotion and conversion respectively). Either way you can get from a char to either a double or an int - so it is ambiguous.

Comment: @Clifford That's _not_ why it is ambiguous.  It's ambiguous because for the first parameter, there is an exact match for the first function, so it is better, and because for the second parameter, the promotion `char` to `int` is "better" than the conversion `char` to `double`, so the second function is better.  Without this distinction, the first function would be better for the first argument, both functions would be equal for the second, and the compiler would choose the first.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Ah! I see your point.  I missed that the first parameter of the first was a `char`;  you are right casting just the first parameter to `int` resolves the ambiguity.  However you really should have posted your own answer perhaps?

Comment: @Clifford I would have, but both Sebastian Redl and Angew basically covered the point before I'd seen the question.

Comment: @JamesKanze:  Then I am embarrassed that this so far has higher upvotes!  I think I've fixed it, but only by stealing your input.

Answer (score 4):

There are `implicit` conversions between `double`, `int`, and `char` in C++, so you should use `static_cast<int>` to convert data from `char` to `int` for example.

```
function( static_cast<int>(c), static_cast<int>(d) );
```

this will call `function( int, int );`

In your particular case, you use `'a'` and `'b'` character literals, which, as I mentioned above, have `implicit conversions` to `int` and `double`, because a `char` variable represents the ASCII value of the character entered in the `assignment operator`. Hence, we can initialize an `unsigned char` variable, or a `char` in the ways below:

```
unsigned char a = 97; // the ASCII decimal code for "a"
unsigned char b = 'a'; // translates into 97
```

Since an `unsigned char` or `char` variables is an 8 bits variable, and `int` is a 32 bit value, they have implicit conversions.

Answer (score 2):

For overload A to be chosen over overload B, the conversions for each argument to A must be as good or better than those for B, and at least one must be better.

In your case, A has (exact match, integral->floating), whereas B has (integral promotion, integral promotion).

Exact match is better than integral promotion, but integral promotion is better than integral->floating conversion. So A has a better conversion in the first argument, and B in the second. So it's ambiguous which one is better overall.

Answer (score 1):

Trying `('a', 'b')` for `function(char, double)` requires no conversion for `'a'`, and a floating-integral conversion for `'b'` (from `char` to `double`).

For `function(int, int)`, both `'a'` and `'b'` require integral promotion (from `char` to `int`).

Comment: And of course, integral promotion is a better match than floating-integral.  (It's sort of implicit in what you write, but it's worth pointing out.)