# C++ ambiguity while overloading cast operator

Tags: c++, c++11

Found:
[Ambiguity while overloading the cast operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476792/ambiguity-while-overloading-the-cast-operator?lq=1)

and

[C++ Operator Ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384200/c-operator-ambiguity)

not helpful

Situation:

Inside the container class's body I have:

```
operator T& () const {
    return *data;
}

operator const T& () const {
    return *data;
}
```

The intent being that:

```
container<object> test = new object;
object& whatever = test; //<--uses (T&) cast
const object& other = test; //<--uses (const T&) cast
```

However the second one causes an error because it is ambiguous.

I completely see why the compiler is complaining, it is okay to assign a `object&` and a `const object&` to a `const object&` however I'd like it to not complain and choose the second (return `const object&`)

Oh wait, just got my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Even though they're different conversion operators (not just overloads of one), the ambiguity is resolved by removing the `const` you have on the first one.

Thus:

```
operator T& () {
    return *data;
}

operator const T& () const {
    return *data;
}
```

Alternatively, if it really makes sense to provide non-`const` access to the pointed to data via a `const` object, then just do

```
operator T& () const {
    return *data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop being silly. As I said you may assign a `object&` or a `const object&` to a `const object&` so the first cast operator is sufficient for the job in either case.

Silly me. Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Depending on the semantics you want (whether the data held by a `const` container should be mutable), it may make more sense to make the first overload non-`const` instead.